# How to make links added from JSON clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, append

I am trying to append links from a JSON file but their `onClick` is not working.

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" id = "views">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="view-type" data-toggle="dropdown" data-selected="high_level"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">High Level View</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="view-type" style="height: 35vh; overflow: auto;">
      <h7 class="dropdown-header">View Type</h7>
      <a class="dropdown-item filter-option active" href="javascript:void(0);" id="high_level">High Level View</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Javascript:

```
d3.json(theURL, function(error, data) {
 if (error) throw error;
 var unique = [];
 data.forEach(function(e){
 if(unique.indexOf(e.segment) == -1){
  unique.push(e.segment);
 }
});
unique.forEach(d =>
$('#views .dropdown-menu').append(`<a class="dropdown-item filter-option ecodes" href="javascript:void(0);" id="${d.substring(0, 4)}">${d}</a>`)
)
if($('#all').hasClass('active') == true) {
  $('.ecodes').remove();
}
});


$('.filter-option').on('click', function() {
  let text = $(this).text(); 
  let selected = $(this).prop('id'); 
  $(this).parent().parent().children('a').text(text);
  $(this).parent().parent().children('a').data().selected = selected;
  filters[$(this).parent().parent().children('a').prop('id').replace('-','_')] = selected;

 $.each($(this).parent().children('a'), function(i,d) 
 $(d).removeClass('active'); });
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I cant seem to figure out why my links aren't working. I need `onClick` for them to have the class `active`.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: @Geshode, my JSON data isn't the problem, I am able to grab that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the static element as a starter then delegating the dynamic node(child node) inside the on method

```
 $('dropdown-menu').on('click','.filter-option', function() {
      let text = $(this).text(); 
      let selected = $(this).prop('id'); 
      $(this).parent().parent().children('a').text(text);
      $(this).parent().parent().children('a').data().selected = selected;
      filters[$(this).parent().parent().children('a').prop('id').replace('-','_')] = selected;

     $.each($(this).parent().children('a'), function(i,d) 
     $(d).removeClass('active'); });
     $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delegate the click to the parent element that exists in the page before you inject new links.

jQuery's `on` method accepts a selector as the second argument so you can update the following line:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', '.filter-option', function() {
  let text = $(this).text(); 
  let selected = $(this).prop('id'); 
  $(this).parent().parent().children('a').text(text);
  $(this).parent().parent().children('a').data().selected = selected;
  filters[$(this).parent().parent().children('a').prop('id').replace('-','_')] = selected;

 $.each($(this).parent().children('a'), function(i,d) 
 $(d).removeClass('active'); });
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events